# Finding the keys of map with the highest values (equality may occur)

Tags: java, generics, playing-cards

I am currently implementing a Poker game, I have created all the logic for getting the rank of a hand, and I now have to determine the winner of a given hand.

Due to this being Poker, there may be multiple winners in a round. I, therefore, need to find **all** the keys (`Player`) that have the best hand (regardless of how many there are).

```
   public Map<Player, Hand> determineWinner(Map<Player, Hand> hands) {
        // Initialize worst possible hand (any hand beats this) - less verbose than
        // having to get a random element form the map
        Hand currentBestHand = new Hand(RankType.HIGH_CARD, CardRank.DEFAULT, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
        Map<Player, Hand> bestHands = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Player, Hand> playerAndHand : hands.entrySet()) {
            int comparisonValue = playerAndHand.getValue().compareTo(currentBestHand);
            if (comparisonValue > 0) {
                currentBestHand = playerAndHand.getValue();
                bestHands.clear();
                bestHands.put(playerAndHand.getKey(), playerAndHand.getValue());
            } else if (comparisonValue == 0) {
                bestHands.put(playerAndHand.getKey(), playerAndHand.getValue());
            }
        }
        return bestHands;
    }
```

However, I am using Java 8 and thus a lot of streams. I couldn't figure out a (pretty) way to implementing the above in streams, and therefore ended up coding it in a loop. I welcome any suggestions, especially those related to writing it succinctly and efficiently using Java 8 streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use streams you'd have to make the score part of the object (at least on an intermediate level) so that you can find the maximum based on the score.

Here's a little example based on a string/string map and String.length() as score replacement (as I don't have your original objects). Should be sufficient to illustrate the idea:

```
    Map<String, String> m = ...

    Map<Integer, List<Entry<String, String>>> intermediateByScore = m.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue().length()));

    Entry<Integer, List<Entry<String, String>>> highest = intermediateByScore.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getKey().compareTo(e1.getKey()))
        .findFirst()
        .get();

    Map<String, String> result = highest.getValue().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

... or, after a few inlines of intermediate variables:

```
    Map<String, String> result = m.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getValue().length()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getKey().compareTo(e1.getKey()))
        .findFirst()
        .get().getValue().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Is this better than the loop: I don't personally think so. My advice: stick to your loop or revise your data structures to better support this approach.

Comment: `(e1, e2) -> e2.getKey().compareTo(e1.getKey())` can be represented as [`Map.Entry.comparingByKey().reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey--). Also, `e -> e.getKey()/e -> e.getValue()` can be represented using the [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `Entry::getKey/Entry::getValue`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Constants

```
// Initialize worst possible hand (any hand beats this)...
Hand currentBestHand = new Hand(RankType.HIGH_CARD, CardRank.DEFAULT, 
                                new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());
```

This sounds like a good candidate for creating a constant `LOWEST_HAND`, as an example:

```
public class Hand implements Comparable<Hand> {

    public static final Hand LOWEST_HAND = new Hand(RankType.HIGH_CARD, CardRank.DEFAULT, 
                                                    emptyList(), emptyList());

    // ...
}
```

Over here, I have opted for the use of [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) to make it clearer that anything is 'better' than an empty, immutable `List`.

#### Sorting with a `TreeMap`

You can consider using a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to *slightly simplify* the sorting of `Hand` for you:

```
TreeMap<Hand, Map<Player, Hand>>> map = hands.entrySet().stream().collect(
                                    groupingBy(Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new, toMap(
                                                    Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
```

Similar to [@mtj](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153365/24141)'s answer, we use [`Collectors.groupingBy(Function, Supplier, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) with the additional parameters to specify the `Map` supplier and the downstream `Collector` with [`Collectors.toMap(Function, Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-).

With the `TreeMap`, we can then use [`TreeMap.lastEntry()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#lastEntry--) to get the entry with the largest `Hand` and return the desired `Map` output:

```
public static Map<Player, Hand> determineWinner(Map<Player, Hand> hands) {
    return hands.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new,
                                toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)))
            .lastEntry()
            .getValue();
}
```